# Can Jenkins support 2 Java versions for same Maven job?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, version

We are trying to upgrade Java and have modified pom.xml to use the new version in source and target for the build. Jenkins job is currently failing with error:

> Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11.

We have multiple release branches being developed in parallel. Most of them are still using old Java and should be built with older version. Only for one release branch we want the new Java version. Is it possible to configure Jenkins in such a way?

My understanding is Jenkins JAVA HOME need to be updated to match the target version.

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the [`--release` compiler option for `javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627). Controlling this through the [`release`-property of the `maven-compiler-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release) seems promising.

Comment: Re 1.: What do you mean by "_Jenkins Java HOME_"? There's the JAVA_HOME environment variable in your OS which Java-based tools consider.

Comment: The Pipeline syntax provides a means to select which JDK you want for a specific run, and this can be parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

*Manage Jenkins* → *Global Tool Configuration* → *JDK installations...* → <kbd>Add JDK</kbd>

<project> → *Configure* → *General* → *JDK* (*JDK to be used for this project*)